# How to determine if a date is in the final week of a month using Excel

Tags: excel, date

example: Today is June 16th. That date is during the 3rd week of its month. This June has days falling on 5 different weeks, so days within the 5th week are within this month's final week. For this month, only the 26th through the 30th fall within the month's final week.

Given all that, how can I determine if a given date is within the final week of its month?

Comment: Using VBA or an Excel formula ?

Comment: either is fine, but I prefer a Excel formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF(A1>=INT((EOMONTH(A1,0)-1)/7)*7+1,"True","False")
```

Comment: I was trying this with `WEEKNUM()` but this option is better.

Comment: yeah, weeknum is tempting, but it doesn't quite address this problem